# Stacking where, or, to filter in ruby on rails causes abnormal results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently trying to filter results for sports venues using where, or in ruby on rails.  I am stacking the city, state, street, and zipcode.  If I search for miami; however, a result with a street address tamiami will appear.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening? the code is as follows.

```
    if location
      records = arel_table
      result = SportsVenue.where(records[:city].matches("%#{location}%")).or(
        SportsVenue.where(records[:state].matches("%#{location}%"))).or(
          SportsVenue.where(records[:zip_code].matches("%#{location}%"))).or(
          SportsVenue.where(records[:street_address].matches("%#{location}%")))

      result = result.where(sport_id: sport.id)
    else
      result = where(sport_id: sport.id)
    end
```

Comment: If you need searches specific to each field in the search query, you should be searching with one parameter each for city, state, zip_code and street_address. If you want to use the current query and match exactly for miami remove the '%' from the string and it will search exactly for miami. So it'd be `SportsVenue.where(records[:city].matches("#{location}"))`

Comment: The question is what is the required result? If you want to match names only with the start of the string you should remove the first % as Moiz suggested. Also, you should consider using different database for those kind of tasks. I recommend ElasticSearch.
It looks like 'tamiami' should be included in the results but not on the top. With ES, it will be possible to return sorted results by a score. So Miami will be on top, and then 'tamiami' or/and other results.